# How do I get output impedence of ICs?

Tags: 555, low-pass

I am teaching electronics a few people as a hobby. I wanted to show them that as the frequency increases output voltage of low pass filter(simple first order RC filter) decreases. I don't have a signal generator to produce frequencies. I am using 555/556 timers for this purpose. But for correct filter output calculations I need to know what is the output impedence of these ICs. But those information is not present in the datasheet. How do I calculate this output impedence?

Comment: put an op amp follower on your output stage, and then the output impedance is a few ohms and you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Surely it's best to use sinewaves to demonstrate filters and the 555 produces a square wave (rich in harmonics).

Comment: @ScottSeidman: But to get the cutoff frequency don't I need the exact resistance value?

Comment: An op-amp's output impedance (as a unity gain buffer) is going to be an ohm or so at audio so, add the 1 ohm to the filter resistance of (say) 1 kohm and you get a 0.1% error. At 1 MHz the op-amp has to be chosen carefully but less than 10 ohms is definitely realistic.

Comment: There is no such thing as "exact".  There is a specification of how close you need to be.  Think about what the error will be if, for example, your filter is designed with a 10K input impedance at DC, and you have a source with an output impedance of 4 ohms as opposed to 0 ohms.

Comment: Output impedance is, as always, voltage drop/lift divided by current.

Comment: The output circuit of a 555 is a complimentary pair quite capable of driving currents (source and sink) up to 200mA, so for all practical purposes just ignore the output impedance - just make sure you use reasonable size resistors for the filter (> 1k0)

Comment: You could actually work out the output impedance by constructing a couple of filters and measuring their properties - there will be a small error which you can work back in the equations to give the impedance.

Comment: @InQusitive: If you add a schematic of the circuit you are teaching you will get a better response. I suspect you are confusing passive RC filters with active which have output impedance of only a few ohms.

Comment: Spend an afternoon characterising the impedance of a few different ICs.  Learn a bunch I expect, I would.  I think in the 10 to 1000 Ohm depending on technology and IC application.  Also many technologies (and function pins) have unequal push and pull impedances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't require this number for a well-designed circuit. For light loads on a CMOS output timer you might be able to find a number, but generally it's variable with power supply voltage, state (it's asymmetrical) load, temperature, unit-to-unit etc. and there will be a big nonlinear component in bipolar output timers even with a light load.

**If you want a controlled output impedance add some resistance** such as a few K ohms to the unknown (but very low) resistance of the timer output.

A TLC555 has "typical" output resistance of about 80 ohms (high, at 10mA) and 12 ohms (low, at 10mA) with a 15V supply. With a 5V supply it's 200 ohms (high, at 1mA) and 25 ohms (low, at 3.2mA). If you connect a capacitor directly to such an output your predictions will be *way* off if based on those resistance values since the MOSFETs do not behave like resistors when their drain-source voltage gets close to the threshold voltage (they behave more like constant current sources).

I generally use 50-100 ohms for the **open-loop** output impedance of an op-amp. Sometimes a typical value is given on the datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

Output impedance is not usually given in logic IC datasheets, because this is not important for digital signals.

However, you can approximate it with some information given in the datasheet: take the voltage drop at high level (Vcc - Voh) and divide it by the current for which the Voh is specified. You'll get an idea of the output impedance for the high level. You can do the same for the low-level: Vol / I (it may be different than for high level, for older chips)

For the NE555, it gives, for a 5V supply (based on [ti datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne555.pdf)):

- for high level: (5V - 3.3V) / 100mA = 17Ohm
- for low level: 0.15V / 8mA = 18.75Ohm